# Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в конструкции "такими же или ещё более … чем"?

Tags: пунктуация

Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в предложении "Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же(,) или еще более(,) жестокими, чем СС"?
Я, к сожалению, не могу понять, чем является "или еще более". Возможно, присоединительным оборотом?

Я бы писал так: они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же, или еще более жестокими, чем СС

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! We here prefer to answer questions which elaborate a little bit more on the problem. Could you please add more detail to your question? What research have you done so far? Did you reach any conclusion? Why are you not happy with it? And so on. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi, к сожалению, я не могу найти никакой информации по этому вопросу, в интернете конструкций с "или еще более" в моем контексте практически нет.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you feel this sentence to be off is that these two clauses require different conjunctions: *такими же жестокими, как* but *более жестокими, чем*.

But that's OK in Russian and you can reuse a conjunction.

You don't need a comma between these clauses:

> - Нужны и другие, которые обладали бы такой же или более высокой, чем стрептомицин, способностью подавлять туберкулезные палочки
> - Этнография не знает ни одного отсталого народа, будь он таким же или еще более первобытным, чем, скажем, австралийцы или огнеземельцы прошлого века, который не имел бы своего звукового языка
> - Мы видим, что незабвенный автор Славянских Древностей превращению Финских Болгар в Славян находит аналогию в таком же или еще более быстром превращении Скандинавской Руси тоже в Славян

Comment: Я являюсь носителем языка и, что забавно, никогда не видел такой конструкции, но спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания здесь не нужны, т.к. союз "или" соединяет два однородных члена, "такими же" и "еще более".